# How to make a 3D compass in Unity? similar to the transform compass in scene mode

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a 3D compass in unity, like the one in scene mode.
But its not looking to bright.
[At the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNK5O.png)

[end goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i21rg.png) How do I better emulate the scene mode transform compass? and keep the GamObject "3DCompass" always in view? (without putting it under the Main Camera)

```
//Compass3D
public class Compass3D : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 NorthDir;
    public Transform Player; // Camera

    public GameObject NorthLayer;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        ChangeNorthDir();
    }

    public void ChangeNorthDir()
    {
        NorthDir.z = Player.eulerAngles.y; //May need to change
        NorthLayer.transform.eulerAngles = NorthDir;

    }
}
```

Comment: Heres the 3Dmodel: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j819az1okgj5ay7/3DCompass_SelectedObj.fbx?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm...

Well, firstly, you need to realize that the compass' orientation never changes. That's kind of the point of it. The compass always points the same way, meaning it doesn't rotate.
Meaning there's no need for you to do anything in update, you just set where the north is supposed to point to, and leave it at that. The illusion of it rotating comes from person rotating, while the compass keeps pointing the same (global) direction.

The second thing is a big, lazy, awesome secret I'm going to tell you about:
[Quaternion.LookRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html)

So what you need to do is just rotate the compass correctly on Start, meaning rotate it so that its "Forward direction" is Vector3.forwards (that's a global Z+), and its upward is Vector3.up (global y+). And then never touch the rotation again.

But you want it to stay in view (without being childed to the camera), so what you'll do in update is that:

```
public class Compass3D : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 NorthDir;
    public Transform Player; // Camera

    public Vector3 offsetFromPlayer; //needed to keep position from camera. this basically determines where on screen the compass will be positioned. 0,0,0 would be at the same position as the camera, experiment with other values to find one which positions compass relative to camera in such way that it displays on screen where you want it

    public GameObject NorthLayer;

    void Start()
    {
      //northDir can be whatever you want, I'm going to assume you want it to point along Unity's forward axis
      NorthDir = Vector3.forward;

      //set the compass to point to north (assuming its "N" needle points in the direction of model's forward axis (z+). if not, change the model, or nest it into a gameobject within which you'll rotate the model so that the N points along the parent gameobject's z+ axis
      NorthLayer.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(NorthDir, Vector3.up);
      //nothing else needed, the rotation will be fine forever now. if you want to change it later, just do the above line again, and supply it the new NorthDir
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
      //only thing you need to do in update, is keep the relative position to camera. tbh, easiest way would be to parent the compass, but you said you don't want that, so...
      transform.position = Player.position + (Player.rotation * offsetFromPlayer);
      //you need to make sure that the compass' offset from camera rotates with the direction of the camera itself, otherwise when camera rotates, the compass will get out of view. that's what multiplying by Player.rotation is there for. you rotate Vectors by multiplying them with quaternions (which is how we express rotations). 
    }
}
```

What this code does: first it sets the compass so it points towards north. And then it never touches that again, because once the compass points towards north, if it's not parented to anything (which I assume it's not), it will keep pointing north. IF it is parented to anything else, just copypaste that line from start to Update too, so that when the orientation of compass' parent changes, the compass fixes its pointing back to global north.

Then, in update, it only updates its position, to keep at the same place relative to camera. The important thing to note is that the position needs to take the camera's direction into account, so that when camera rotates, the compass moves similarly to if you had your hand outstretched in front of you, and you rotated your whole body. If the compass is not parented to anything, that motion the tip of your hand does is still just a position change, but it is position relative to your whole body and its direction, so that position change needs to take that into account.

In this code, if you put the offsetFromPlayer as Vector3(0,0,1), that would mean "one unit along the way the camera is looking". If you put it as Vector3(1,0,1), that would mean "one unit along the way the camera is looking, and one unit to the right". So you'll need to experiment with that value to find one that makes the compass display where you actually want it to be on the screen.

Comment: @ChrisSimmons
...wait, have you already tried it and it works? =D

i was a bit unsure about the position line, because I also tend to have trouble with these kinds of code, as in, the idea behind it is correct, but sometimes it takes me a few tries to express it exactly correctly in code, and this one I haven't tried, just wrote it off the top of my head in the hopes "it should be the right one" =D O:-)

Comment: When ever I move the compass moves away, shaking happens too, ill "try" fix this. Thank you again you've helped a ton Cheers

Comment: "When ever I move the compass moves away"

don't forget to assign the Camera reference to the compass's Player variable, in inspector.

regarding the shaking, it might get solved if you change the Update to be LateUpdate. the jerking probably happens because the compass updates its position before camera, it gets so the new, appropriate one a frame too late.

if you change the function in compass to LateUpdate, you make sure it happens after all other Update functions in the whole game have ran, including whatever updates the camera position itself.